# Circular compositional pattern with RSS Feed and FeedItem classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns, rss, composition

I'm designing a small system to parse RSS feeds, and I have two classes: Feed and FeedItem.

```
public class Feed
{
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string Link{ get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsTwitterFeed { get; set; }
    public List<FeedItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class FeedItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Link{ get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Feeds have FeedItems, and FeedItems have parent Feeds. Would it be a bad pattern to give the FeedItem class a parent Feed member:

```
public Feed ParentFeed { get; set; }
```

so I could do this:

```
// get the latest item from the latest feed, then print its parent feed name
FeedItem item = Feeds.GetLatest().Item[0];
Response.Write(item.ParentFeed.Name + ": " + item.Title);
```

or should I only ever get a FeedItem through its parent Feed, to avoid this circular reference between these two classes?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the parent then you could store it as an `object`. It would be necessary if you can get a `FeedItem` through some other route than from the `Feed` and need to get to the `Feed`. However, it's not particularly elegant.

This is usually done in cases where there can be different types of parent object.

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't your caller just store the reference to the Feed?

```
Feed latest = Feeds.GetLatest();
FeedItem item = latest.Item[0];
Response.Write(latest.Name + ": " + item.Title);
```

Edit: Personally I'd avoid the circular reference if possible but I guess that's just a matter of taste!?